# Why I get ** (EXIT) bad return value: :ok

Tags: elixir

I need to let a `GenServer` monitor a task, thus, I do:

```
GenServer.call(server_pid, {:monitor_task, self()})
```

in server:

```
def handle_call({:monitor_task, task_pid}, _from, state) do
  ref = Process.monitor(task_pid)
  {:reply, ref, state}
end
```

however, I get error:

```
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.768.0>, {:monitor_task, #PID<0.849.0>}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) bad return value: :ok
```

Any idea?

Comment: I copied your code into a new GenServer and it works fine. Can you post the whole code which throws that error?

Comment: there https://gist.github.com/hopewise/06e2540b8d542395bc10bf80245995b8 , just search for : monitor_task

Comment: And can you add the complete error message (with stacktrace)?

Comment: Kindly check comment under gist above.

Comment: Does it look normal?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't spot anything obvious based on the stacktrace and code. Maybe someone else will. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154066/discussion-between-simo-and-dogbert).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `handle_info` callbacks with calls to Logger need to return `{:noreply, state}` or `{:stop, reason, state}`, but the calls to Logger return `:ok`, which is an invalid return value for the callback, and is what caused the error you are seeing.

Comment: Definitely the right answer for this question. For other people coming here: I had the same error message but for me the problem was, that I forgot to return the state along with the reply. So far I returned `{:reply, return_value}` when I should have returned `{:reply, return_value, state}` in the last line of my handle_call implementation